# how to pan two maps simultaneously overlay using div

Tags: javascript, html, overlay, pan

I am having two maps which are overlayed  using div. However whenever I pan the map, only the map above the base map moves and not the base map. Kindly tell if there is some way to let the mouse panning enabled for both the maps simultaneously.
Thanks
Astha

```
<style type='text/css'>
/*<![CDATA[*/

.modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
.overlay {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 800px;
    height: 532px;
   position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}

.message {
    width: 800px;
    height: 532px;

    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: .35;
    filter: alpha(opacity=35);
    position:absolute;
     pointer-events:none;
}




    /*]]>*/
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://nls.tileserver.com/api.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?    file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAA9pSslyaYyyl6x8HKrHAZvxS4-alJFZ9Cxp3qiYSlGHIYxF9uHhT0NLb9B9BXGUGGDctSO4QVa1jLLA" type="text/javascript">
</script> 
<script src="http://nls.tileserver.com/opacity-control.js" type="text/javascript">       </script> 
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

function whereami(lat, lon) {
load(lat,lon);
}
/*
function pull() {
var location=JSON.parse(locater.getLocation());

whereami(location.lat, location.lon);
}*/
function load(latitude,longitude)
{

 if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    //var latitude = 55.96;
    //var longitude = -3.2;
    var MyIcon = new GIcon();
    var zoom = 18;
    var map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(latitude,longitude), zoom);
    var copyright = new GCopyright(1, new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(-90, -180),new GLatLng(90, 180)), 1,
    "Historical maps from <a href='http://geo.nls.uk/maps/api/'>NLS Maps API<\/a>");
    var copyrightCollection = new GCopyrightCollection();
    copyrightCollection.addCopyright(copyright);



    var tilelayer = new GTileLayer(copyrightCollection, 1, NLSTileUrlOS('MAXZOOM'));
    tilelayer.getTileUrl = NLSTileUrlOS;
    var nlsmap = new GMapType([tilelayer], G_NORMAL_MAP.getProjection(), "Historical");
    map.addMapType(nlsmap);
    map.setMapType(nlsmap);

    var map1 = new GMap(document.getElementById("map1"));
    map1.setCenter(new GLatLng(latitude,longitude), zoom);
    var copyright = new GCopyright(1, new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(-90, -180),new GLatLng(90, 180)), 1,
    "Historical maps from <a href='http://geo.nls.uk/maps/api/'>NLS Maps API<\/a>");
    var copyrightCollection = new GCopyrightCollection();
    copyrightCollection.addCopyright(copyright);

    var tilelayer = new GTileLayer(copyrightCollection, 1, NLSTileUrlOS('MAXZOOM'));
    tilelayer.getTileUrl = NLSTileUrlOS;
    var nlsmap = new GMapType([tilelayer], G_NORMAL_MAP.getProjection(), "Historical");
    map1.addMapType(nlsmap);
    map1.setMapType(nlsmap);
    // put div over map
Position.clone($("map"), $("map1").setStyle({'pointer-events': 'none'}), {offsetLeft:100, offsetTop:62.5, setWidth:false, setHeight:false});


    var marker = new GMarker( new GLatLng(latitude,longitude));
    var myIcon=new GIcon(marker.getIcon());
    myIcon.image='pushpin.png';
    myIcon.iconSize = new GSize (40,40);
    var marker2 = new GMarker( new GLatLng(latitude,longitude), myIcon);
    map.addOverlay(marker2);




    }
}
</script >
</head>
<body onload = whereami(55.96,-3.2)>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="overlay" id="map">

    </div>
    <div class="message" id="map1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably u can use getCenter from map 1 and use latlang to setCenter of second on events u are moving mouse

Comment: so you are saying that i can call a function which will do what you stated whenever mouse is pressed !! ?

Comment: Not exactly, when u drag the map, on each drag or move event, get the center (latlang) of the map and set center that latlang to other map

Comment: ok. Thanks but i am somewhat new to all these things so if u have any sample please tell.

Comment: I was able to get it using GEvent. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Thats great, u make it ur own.